# How to get array from JSON format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, autocomplete

I have something like this...

```
["a","b","c"]
```

I got it from PHP array using json_decode(). I'm very weak in JavaScript, but I need to get array in Javascript, so I can use it with jQuery UI -> Autocomplete like this...

```
source: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Is it possible to do with only Javascript or you need to have some Javascript library to use JSON?

Comment: Consider: `<script>var myObj = <?= encode_your_php_object_to_json(...) ?>;</script>` and what it implies. See http://www.json.org for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but I need to get array in Javascript,
>   so I can use it with jQuery UI ->
>   Autocomplete

Check out [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Hey,
You can do it only with javascript:

```
var arrayToUse = ["a","b","c"];
```

JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation and it is a standard notation for javascript objects. You do not need any special library to use it. Example,

If you want to create an object in javascript you would do something like:

```
var person = {
 name : 'somename',
source : arrayToUse
};
```

This is a javascript object in JSON notation

Comment: *"JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation and it is a standard notation for javascript objects."* That's a bit misleading. The standard notation for JavaScript objects is JavaScript object liternal notation. JSON is a *subset* of object literal notation.

Comment: JSON is more restrictive than JavaScript -- it is a valid *subset*. For instance, all keys *must* be quoted to be valid JSON. The grammar "tracks" can be followed at http://www.json.org